# SSH Hangs on "Entering interactive session" stage

Tags: ssh, openssh, yocto

I built an image with yocto project for Banana Pro board. I am trying to connect port via `ssh root@10.1.80.x` but I couldn't.

Ssh always hangs on the `Entering interactive session` stage. When I run `ssh -v` parameter, I captured below logs :

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015 
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for * 
debug1: Connecting to 10.1.80.41 [10.1.80.41] port 22. 
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
debug1: identity file /home/yusuf/.ssh/id_rsa type -1 
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
debug1: identity file /home/yusuf/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
debug1: identity file /home/yusuf/.ssh/id_dsa type -1 
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
debug1: identity file /home/yusuf/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
debug1: identity file /home/yusuf/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1 
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
debug1: identity file /home/yusuf/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
debug1: identity file /home/yusuf/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1 
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
debug1: identity file /home/yusuf/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1 
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0 
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1 
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000 
debug1: Authenticating to 10.1.80.41:22 as 'root' 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent              
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received 
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com none 
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com none 
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY 
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
 SHA256:XpqS0ZXhoF/OsBmiD8bkpWaZ6Fbk5T3a2Xdq2E8127w 
The authenticity of    host '10.1.80.41 (10.1.80.41)' can't be established. ECDSA key
 fingerprint is SHA256:XpqS0ZXhoF/OsBmiD8bkpWaZ6Fbk5T3a2Xdq2E8127w. Are
 you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes 
Warning:
Permanently added '10.1.80.41' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST
 sent 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (none). Authenticated to 10.1.80.41 ([10.1.80.41]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session] 
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com 
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

I tried to change MTU but it didn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual ssh command that you're running which produces this result.

Comment: Please, could you apart from supplying the actual command, also ensure that you have line breaks in the log? Currently, it's extremely hard to read.

Comment: I edited my question. I run "ssh root@10.1.80.x" command

Comment: Please take note that the copy and pasted log you sent is extremely hard to read and needs to have line breaks in between.  Please put some effort into clearing those up in future questions. Thanks

Comment: Server's ssh version is OpenSsh 7.1 and clients OpenSSH 6.9.Is this a problem?Must two side's versions be same?

Comment: I am trying to connect to board now.It hangs on "excepting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY" stage.Please help me about this problem.

Comment: The debug trace in the question shows that you're authenticating and starting a session; the server just isn't printing a command prompt or anything else. Now you say ssh is hanging at an earlier point of starting up? It appears the root problem is that the host which you're connecting to isn't very healthy. You should troubleshoot proper operation of the server rather than your client.

Comment: Yes.Problems on host. Because I tried to connect another board via same client and I connected sucessfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem has been solved purely by chance.And I don't know why.

Normally, I had been running `modprobe sunxi-gmac` and `/etc/init.d/networking restart` commands manually after booting with ethernet cable attached.
But this time, accidentally,I forgot to plug the cable beforehand, but plugged during `/etc/init.d/networking restart` command was running (Sending discover stage).
To my surprise, ssh connection has been achieved! This behaviour is deterministic(Tried enough).

Can anyone explain this weird situation? Why should I plug the ethernet cable during network is restarting and not before that?